# Differential equation for describing a falling chain

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I'm trying to solve a problem which involves finding the final velocity of a chain as it falls off a table.

A chain of uniform mass is on a table with negligible friction. Length $b$ hangs off the table and length $a$ is on the table. Find the velocity as the last link leaves the table.

$$F = mg = \frac{dP}{dt}$$

$$\frac{\partial{m}}{\partial{t}} = \dot{m}v$$

$$\frac{\partial{m}}{\partial{t}} = ma$$

Therefore

$$mg = \dot{m}v + ma.$$

I assume that if I can solve this equation then that'll lead to the solution of this problem. However, the equation involves a first and second order derivative. I've never solved one of these before.

What is the right way to go about completing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use conservation of energy.  The length $b$ has moved downward by $a$ at the time the last link falls.  The length $a$ has moved downward by $\frac a2$ at the time the last link falls.  If we assume the linear density is $1$ (a different value will divide out) we have lost $g(ab+\frac {a^2}2)$ in potential energy.  We have gained $\frac 12v^2(a+b)$ in kinetic energy.  These must be equal, so 
$$g\left(ab+\frac {a^2}2\right)=\frac 12(a+b)v^2\\
v=\sqrt{\frac{2g\left(ab+\frac {a^2}2\right)}{a+b}}$$

Comment: A much simpler method! Thanks :)

Comment: +1 for a good answer. One note: if one end of the chain is suspended and remains suspended, instead of sliding off the table, then the energy approach gets exceedingly tricky. In fact, it wasn't until the 1980's that physicists solved the problem correctly! There's a discussion of it in Marion and Thornton, I forget where. The trickiness had to do with the chunk of chain that was going from moving to stationary, and how conservation of energy worked there. The net result was that the chain was falling faster than the previous model predicted.

Answer (score 2):

Define $y$ positive down, and zero at the top of the table. I think you need to make some more careful distinctions. In Newton's Second Law, $F=\dot{p},$ the $p$ on the RHS is relevant, in your case, to the entire chain. Let $M$ be the mass of the entire chain, and let $\ell=a+b$ be the total length of the chain. Then $p=M\dot{y}.$ It follows that $\dot{p}=M\ddot{y}.$ Let $m$ be the mass of the vertical section, corresponding to $y$. Then the force on the chain is $mg$. Let $\lambda=M/\ell$ be the linear mass density. Newton's Second Law then tells us that 
\begin{align*}
mg&=M\ddot{y} \\
\lambda yg&=M\ddot{y} \\
\frac{M}{\ell}yg&=M\ddot{y} \\
\ddot{y}&=\frac{g}{\ell}\,y.
\end{align*}
This DE has the solution 
$$y=Ae^{t\sqrt{g/\ell}}+Be^{-t\sqrt{g/\ell}}. $$
The initial conditions are $y(0)=b$ and $\dot{y}(0)=0.$ Solving for $A$ and $B$ yields
\begin{align*}
y(t)&=\frac{b}{2}\,e^{t\sqrt{g/\ell}}+\frac{b}{2}e^{-t\sqrt{g/\ell}} \\
\dot{y}(t)&=\frac{b}{2}\,\sqrt{\frac{g}{\ell}}\,e^{t\sqrt{g/\ell}}-\frac{b}{2}\sqrt{\frac{g}{\ell}}\,e^{-t\sqrt{g/\ell}}.
\end{align*}
We can simplify these expressions by using hyperbolic trig functions:
\begin{align*}
y(t)&=b\cosh\left(t\sqrt{g/\ell}\right) \\
\dot{y}(t)&=b\sqrt{\frac{g}{\ell}}\,\sinh\left(t\sqrt{g/\ell}\right)
\end{align*}
Now then, we must solve for $t$ when $y=\ell,$ then plug that into $\dot{y}$. Can you finish from here?

Alternatively, you could use the hyperbolic trig identity
$$\cosh^2(\theta)-\sinh^2(\theta)=1$$
to eliminate the hyperbolic trig functions entirely (removing the parameter $t$ in the process), and solve for $\dot{y}$ directly. This would be a bit more elegant.